# Usage "Times New Roman" in commercial application

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper Reports in commercial application. I need to use (embed) "Times New Roman" font in generated documents. I found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1653) that this font can be embedded (`Embedding: Editable embedding allowed`). What does it mean ? Can i embed `times.ttf` in application or in documents only ? Can someone explain that ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an FAQ entry on the Microsoft website which gives information on how you can reuse the font. In essence, the rights are in the font files properties -- and on my system, Times New Roman is embeddable for editable documents. The Microsoft website has [an FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/RedistributionFAQ.mspx) which defines the embeddability levels as:

Embedding allows fonts to travel with documents. Most fonts distributed with Microsoft products allow embedding. To check a font's embedding permissions, right-click on the font file and choose 'Properties'.

> There are 4 levels of embedding permissions:
>
> 'Print and preview' fonts can be embedded in a document, provided the user reading the document cannot edit the content of the document.
>
> 'Editable' fonts can be embedded within content that can be edited by the user.
>
> 'Installable' fonts within a document may be permanently installed by the user reading the document or a client application. In practice, installable fonts are treated like editable fonts by most client applications.
>
> 'No embedding permissions' prevent fonts from being embedded in a document.

Comment: Ok. I see that fonts can be embedded in a document. What about distributing this fonts with commercial application inside .jar file ? Is that legal ?